# keepalived - received advertisement timeout

Tags: keepalived, vrrp

I'm trying to setup keepalived between two servers, this servers are in diferent DMZ's.
I already open all necessary ports and the servers are communicating correctly beetween each other, but when i tried to start keepalived I get this meesage in both servers.

```
Mon Oct 10 22:03:18 2022: (xxxx22) Receive advertisement timeout
Mon Oct 10 22:03:18 2022: (xxxx22) Entering MASTER STATE
```

**Configurations**

```
vrrp_instance server1 {
    state Master
    interface ens01 //10.41.134.101/27
    virtual_router_id 253
    priority 200
    advert_int 1
   
    virtual_ipaddress {
               10.41.176.98/27 dev ens01
    }
}

vrrp_instance server2 {
    state Backup
    interface ens01 //10.41.176.97/27
    virtual_router_id 253
    priority 150
    advert_int 1
   
    virtual_ipaddress {
               10.41.176.98/27 dev ens01
    }
}
```

**Diagram:**

[Keepalived diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g83Y3.png)

I already try with multicast and unicast but no lock, so what could be the problem?
VRRP broadcast blocked on firewall?

Comment: Not using the same LAN?

Comment: No, they are in different segments